# Resize UIImageView based on image with respect to UIImageViewWidth

Tags: uiimageview, ios7, frame

I have a UIImageView that is the width of the entire screen and the height is 400 pixels.

The end result I am looking for is that every single image has the exact same width (the screen width) and the height is adjusted to accommodate this while keeping its aspect ratio.

So if an image is 400 pixels wide, it needs to reduce to 320 pixels wide, and the height of the image view should adjust and become SHORTER to keep the ratio.

If an image is 240 pixels wide, it needs to increase its width to 320 and adjust the hight to be TALLER to keep the ratio.

I have been looking through many posts that all seem to just point to setting the content mode to aspect fit, but this does nothing like what I am looking for.

Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like shortly after I posted it, I checked storyboard, and for some reason the code was not overwriting the storyboard.

If I change it to Aspect Fit in storyboard, it actually functions the way it is supposed to.

::face palm::

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set the content mode property to Aspect Fit in your imageview.

Comment: This was something I was doing programmatically, and it did not work. When I changed the property in my storyboard, it worked properly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
UIImage *originalImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"xxx.png"];
    double width = originalImage.size.width;
    double height = originalImage.size.height;
    double apectRatio = width/height;

    //You can mention your own width like 320.0
    double newHeight = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width/ apectRatio;
    self.img.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, newHeight);
    self.img.center = self.view.center;
    self.img.image = originalImage;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func resizeImage(image: UIImage, targetSize: CGSize) -> UIImage {
        let size = image.size

        let widthRatio  = targetSize.width  / image.size.width
        let heightRatio = targetSize.height / image.size.height

        // Figure out what our orientation is, and use that to form the rectangle
        var newSize: CGSize
        if(widthRatio > heightRatio) {
            newSize = CGSize(width: size.width * heightRatio, height: size.height * heightRatio)
        } else {
            newSize = CGSize(width: size.width * widthRatio, height: size.height * widthRatio)
        }

        // This is the rect that we've calculated out and this is what is actually used below
        let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newSize.width, height: newSize.height)

        // Actually do the resizing to the rect using the ImageContext stuff
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 1.0)
        image.draw(in: rect)
        let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return newImage!
    }
```

Now get the resized image from the original image, as I done it like:

```
let image = UIImage(named: "YOUR IMAGE NAME")
let newHeight = (image?.size.height/image?.size.width) * YOUR_UIIMAGE_VIEW_WIDTH
let newSize = CGSize(width: YOUR_UIIMAGE_VIEW_WIDTH, height: newHeight)
let newResizedImage = resizeImage(image: image, targetSize: newSize)
```

Hope, this will help.